# How do I change the site displayed on my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion

The site shown on my profile is wrong. How do I change it? It is currently showing one link of many from my site.

Answer (score 7):

On your Stack Overflow profile, click "Edit Profile & Settings" at the top. Edit accordingly. (If you just want to edit your 'About me', you can do this in the first 'Profile' tab (If your bio is blank, it will say 'Click to edit'))

On the far left of the Stack Overflow profile, there is a shortcut to view your Network ('Stack Exchange') profile, and also to edit the list of SO commmunities that are listed on your profile. If it's your personal site that is incorrect, you can update this in your SO profile. When updating your network profile you can choose to copy info from any of the communities you belong to. If you choose SO, your network profile will be copied accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Stupid question: Where is this? I can't find it.

Comment: This answer is true for almost all websites :) I need to know where "Edit Profile & Settings" button is?

Comment: @mdikici added screenshot of stackoverflow profile tabs. You can click into your own profile by clicking on your name, either in a comment or on the top right of the screen.

Comment: I don't see this screen at all. How did you get there? Is it possible it changed?

Comment: @androiddeveloper At the top of the screen, click on where your name and picture appear on the top right, that will bring you into the profile screen.

Comment: @RachelGallen But then what? Where's the part there that I can edit the photo and description? Can you please check it out, and if it changed, update the answer, with step-by-step screenshots?

Comment: @androiddeveloper click through the tabs. One of them says Profile at the top! Rest of instructions are in the answer.

Comment: @RachelGallen I already tried it. I have "profile" , but nothing there is editable . There is no edit button either. And in your screenshot there are options below "PERSONAL INFORMATION" , but in my case there isn't even one. Look : https://i.imgur.com/bhqJDIA.png . Please check out too.

Comment: There is no way to edit my profile description anywhere. It used to be easy. Now I am hostage to the SO community

Answer (score 1):

Click **Edit** along the top of your profile, and then change the URL under the website. Information like this can be found under **Help** most of the time.